# Moving a Mega Menu Over

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to jquery and css. I created a jquery mega menu but I am having problems with the Link menu item. It runs off the right side of the scren and I want to bring it over to match the right edge of the site. Can someone please explain how I can do this? I normally would post the code or put up a jsfiddle link but there are different css and js files to run this and I don't know of another way then to link you directly to the site.

This style I have linked to the UL of the list for Links

Located in the menu.css file.

```
/* Style the 3rd level links */
.dcjq-mega-menu ul.menu li .sub li ul li#links-layout {

}
```

I have tried float left and also margin-right:300px; and neither seem to effect moving it.

This is on the main page.

```
<li id="links-layout"><a href="#">LINKS</a>
```

Instruction: Roll your mouse over the "LINKS" menu bar item and notice how it runs off the right browser screen I want to fix this.

Here is the link: http://gdisinc.com/barker/default.php

Comment: margin-left on `<ul class="sub"` seems to do it, -204px but that will probably effect all other elements of the same class so you'd need to put an id on that last one and only apply the margin on that mega menu.

Comment: works fine under chrome, but *Contact us* menu item is below *Home*

Comment: @martincarlin87 could you please show me how to do it? I'm new and learning. I was able to get it to move over but as you suggested it moved everything else over.

Comment: @martincarlin87 I put `margin-right: 350px;` on this area is this correct spot? It worked because it moved it over but not sure if I did it right. `.dcjq-mega-menu ul.menu li .sub-container {
position: absolute; /* Required */
background: url(../images/menubar/bg_sub_left.png) no-repeat 0 100%; 
padding-left: 10px; 
margin-left: -3px;
margin-left: 350px;
}`

Comment: @martincarlin87 is the way to create a class for this? `.dcjq-mega-menu ul.menu li .sub-container #linksmenu {` and then I put it here like this? `<li class="linksmenu"><a href="#">LINKS</a>`? Thanks,

Comment: you just change the html for the last menu to `<ul class="sub" id="last-sub"` and in your css, `#last-sub { margin-left: -204px; }` and that should do it.